# How to add easing to this? "Cooler" scrolling. Jquery ScrollTo

Tags: jquery, easing

This code is for navigating down/up a page. It's all working properly, I would just like it to have some more ease. Some animation that looks a little better. Any ideas??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(function() {

```
function scroll(direction) {

    var scroll, i,
            positions = [],
            here = $(window).scrollTop(),
            collection = $('.part');

    collection.each(function() {
        positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset()['top'],10));
    });

    for(i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        if (direction == 'next' && positions[i] > here) { scroll = collection.get(i); break; }
        if (direction == 'prev' && i > 0 && positions[i] >= here) { scroll = collection.get(i-1); break; }
    }

    if (scroll) {
        $.scrollTo(scroll, {
            duration: 350       
        });
    }

    return false;
}

$("#next,#prev").click(function() {        
    return scroll($(this).attr('id'));        
});

$(".scrolltoanchor").click(function() {
    $.scrollTo($($(this).attr("href")), {
        duration: 350
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Comment: Ah thank you, have any idea how I should impliment it? I am a jquery n00b

Comment: @user1691441 `$.scrollTo(scroll, {
    duration: 350,
    easing: "Name of the easing equation"     
});`

Comment: Thanks Michele, I've tried  `if (scroll) {
$.scrollTo(scroll, { duration: 350, easing: "bounceinout"
 });` but it's not working. I must be doing something wrong. (wouldn't doubt it.)

Comment: @user1691441 have you added and linked the easing plugin to your site?